# I got an unused variable in function Store in a controller, $variable = Model::create() (Laravel 9)

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I would like to know how to use Model::create properly, because I don't have any issues, but I have an unused variable that someone explained to me that is normal and should stay there... it just doesn't make any sense for me.

That's my code.

```
public function store(StoreProjectRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->validated();

    $slug = Project::genSlug($request->title);
    $data["slug"] = $slug;

    $newProject = Project::create($data);

    return redirect()->route("admin.projects.index");
}
```

If I hover the `$newProject`, it says "declared but not used".

Can anyone explain me?

Comment: just remove $newProject .. so it reads `Project::create($data)`. You save the return value of Project::create in $newProject - but dont use it.. so if you dont need the return value just dont assign it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create` method on a model returns an instance of the model that was created. If you do not use it anywhere after creating it, there is no point in assigning it to a variable. You can just do this:

```php
Project::create($data);
```

A reason to assign it to a variable could be to redirect to a page that shows the information about the newly created model. Provided you have a route like this:

```php
Route::get('projects/{project}', [ProjectsController::class, 'show'])->name('projects.show');
```

Something like this could make sense in your controller:

```php
public function store(StoreProjectRequest $request)
{
    // ... validation

    $project = Project::create($data);

    return redirect()->route('projects.show', ['project' => $project]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you couldn't be more specific. Thanks again.